# Web application testing with more than 100 users

Tags: application-software-testing

I have to test a web-based live video streaming application. This application sends video from one user to 20 users at the other end. We want to check what happens when the number of users increases from 20 to 100 such as whether 100 users are receiving the video. These 100 users can either log in to laptops, smartphones or tabs. How do I test this scenario?

Comment: You want to test if the application can handle 100 users or you want to test the behaviour of application (video quality etc.) with 100 concurrent users?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Is this video streaming app similar to YouTube/Vimeo, like you're hosting videos? What do you mean by "sends video from 1 user to x users?" Are you sending email/sms links to the video? Sending the actual video (like sending a .mov or .mpeg file)?

Answer (score 1):

Testing a web application with more than 100 users involves:

**Define Objectives:** Clearly outline performance testing goals and metrics.

**Create Scenarios:** Develop realistic user scenarios.

**Choose Tools:** Select tools like JMeter or Gatling for load testing.

**Distributed Testing:** Simulate users from different locations.\

**Monitor Resources:** Track server resources during tests.

**Load Balancer & Database Testing:** Ensure load balancing and optimize database performance.

**Cache Testing:** Validate caching effectiveness under load.

**Scalability Testing:** Gradually increase load to assess system capacity.

**Stress Testing:** Exceed expected load to find system breaking points.

**Reporting & Analysis:** Collect and analyze performance metrics.

**Iterative Testing:** Regularly test with changes to the application.

Comment: It's obvious you copied it from somewhere, without proper attribution.

Answer (score 0):

> These 100 users can either log in to laptops, smartphones or tabs. How do I test this scenario?

Something like [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) should do the trick nicely. @`Dmitri T` has lots of helpful links for a [similar question over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52403889/1106708).